# Output the index of an item in a set in Python/Sage

Tags: python, for-loop, set, max, sage

This is what I have so far.

```
def f(n):
    my_list=[]  
    while n not in my_list: 
        my_list.append(n) 
        if n % 2 == 0: 
            n = n / 2
        else: 
            n =  3 * n + 1 
    my_list.append(n) 
    return my_list
```

The above code takes any input n and outputs a list e.g. f(2) -> [2, 1, 4, 2]

Now I want to look at any range  and output just the highest element in said list.

```
def f_2(i): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        set_f = set(f(i)) 
        print(max(set_f))
```

So I converted the list to a set and applied the max command to it. All of this has worked as I had intended it so far.

My problem is with the following issue:
I want to output all the indexes of all the highest Elements in all generated lists.

E.g. for i in range (1,101): The highest Element is 9232. I tried doing it in the above way, but a set does not have any indexes. However max() does not seem to work on a list of generated lists.

My try was:

```
def f_3(i): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        set_f = set(f(i)) 
        if max(set_f) == 9232:
            print(set_f.index(9232))
        else:
            pass
```

Here I get the error that set has no index attribute.

```
def f_3(i): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        if max(f(i)) == 9232:
            print(f.index(9232))
        else:
            pass
```

Here I get the error that function has no index attribute.

Only the range of 1 to 100 is of interest to me. So I can use 9232 as a value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel a bit stuck on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things to unpack here, and I feel like the Code Review community would be a better fit.

- First of all, why does `f_2` have the parameter `i`? You're just using the `i` from the loop.
- Second, why are you converting the list into a set at all? `max` works just fine on lists too.
- `set` doesn't support indexing, and that's why you were getting that mistake.
- At the other attempt with `f_3`, you've called `index` on *the function* `f` instead of `f(i)`.

Function `f_2` can be rewritten as such.

```
def f_2(): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        lst = f(i)
        mx = max(lst)
        print(lst.index(mx))
```

Function `f_3` is inefficient, but it too can be fixed like this:

```
def f_3(): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        if max(f(i)) == 9232:
            print(f(i).index(9232))
```

Comment: in f_3():

`
def f_3(): 
    for i in range (1,101): 
        if max(f(i)) == 9232:
            print(f(i).index(9232))
`


This outputs the index of the item 9232 in the lists that are generated from 1-100.

I would like to output the originally used number to generate the list e.g. 27, if f(27) contains the Element 9232

I guess just using print(i) works.

Thanks!